# NormalizeObservation in OpenAI Gym

Tags: python, openai-gym

As a beginner in OpenAI gymnasium, my goal is build SAC from scratch and use it to train an agent on Bipedalwalker problem. In order to have a balanced input to SAC, I would like to normalise actions and observation coming from the gym to be between 0 to 1. I find the **RescaleAction** method for actions whereas I could not tell where to use **NormalizeObservation** method... do you think that I can use it when starting the environment then this would apply to all following observations:

```
base_env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v3", render_mode = 'rgb_array')
env = RescaleAction(base_env, min_action=0, max_action=1)
env = NormalizeObservation(env)
```

is this right?
I got confused by the [note](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/wrappers/observation_wrappers/#gymnasium.wrappers.NormalizeObservation) in the documentation.

Comment: yes, it will. You can create a chain of wrappers. Or was your question about whether `NormalizeObservation` is applied episode-based or session-based? If so, then the second, this wrapper is based on so-called running mean and std, and they are updated during **ALL** episodes and are not resetted